# aws spot instance state monitoring

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We recently moved our test environment to spot instances and we've run into one issue we've been unable to solve yet.

One morning we had one of our spot instances not spin up due to the bid being too low.

I'm wondering if there is any way to put some sort of alert on the spot request state to get an email if this happens again.  I haven't found any method within aws themselves so I thought I'd check here.

Thanks to anyone who is willing to give me a hand.

Comment: Did you check this alerts http://aws.amazon.com/code/7808666890647151

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that.  That looks like that will do what we do.  My apologies for wasting your time but thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this monitoring guide for Spot Instances.

http://aws.amazon.com/code/7808666890647151

Comment: Thanks.  My apologies for wasting everyone's time and somehow missing that article.